# how to see .svclogs in windows azure management portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

i am using windows azure and i hosted my application on windows azure management portal, 
i also enable tracing in the web.config file i.e. .svc logs, i am able to check .svc logs in local system but how to check .svc logs in windows azure management portal ?
Please help me about the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see the *.svc logs in the management portal. What you can do is write those logs to a local resource and configure the diagnostic manager to pick up these files and write them to a storage account.

Christian Weyer explains in a blog post how you can do this by extending the existing XmlWriterTraceListener: [Writing trace data to your beloved .svclog files in Windows Azure (aka ‘XmlWriterTraceListener in the cloud’)](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2010/12/writing-trace-data-to-your-beloved-svclog-files-in-windows-azure-aka-xmlwritertracelistener-in-the-cloud.html)

Then I suggest you take a look at Neil's blog post for setting up custom logs (directories): http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/08/custom-diagnostics-in-windows-azure/

Comment: hi i am using windows azure trial account and i am using WCF service so in my azuretracelistener.cs file i define the settings like         public static DirectoryConfiguration GetLogDirectory()
        {
            DirectoryConfiguration directory = new DirectoryConfiguration();
            directory.Container = "wad-tracefiles";
            directory.DirectoryQuotaInMB = 10;
            directory.Path = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("ServiceWebRole.svclog").RootPath;
            return directory;
        } so how to view the .svc logs

Comment: I don't think your GetLocalResource is right. This should be the name of the local resource (the one you defined in the service definition), not the name of the log file itself. Then by connecting to your storage account (with CloudBerry for example) you can view the log files. Note that you need to configure the interval so it might take a few minutes before you can actually see the file.

Comment: in my web.config i define the settings like inside the system.diagnostic tag     <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, 

Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>

Comment: the localresource which i define in .csdef file is like        <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="ServiceWebRole.svclog" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>

Comment: These are your standard Azure trace logs, this has nothing to do with svclogs. If you want to use the svclogs, you'll also need to add an other listener for it. Follow Christian Weyer's blogpost, he explains all this in detail.